# I have declared a global variable in script1,js

Tags: javascript

How can I restrict the global variable to that file only, ie not accessible to other script files, I have two script files like script1,js and script2,js

Comment: Global variables would be accessible to any script declared after it.

`<script src="script1.js"></script>` Has Global
`<script src="script12.js"></script>` Can See Global

l
You could try to include that script last to "block" other scripts from loading it in a sense, but the best method is to create abstract functions and pass around parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You should capsule your code in each file, so you don´t pollute your windows object. Also, you can use "return" to get values from the other file, if needed.